# How to print a row of points (or any other character) in plain TeX?

Tags: plain-tex

I need something like the following

.....................................................................................................................................................................

and something like

(a word)........................................................................................................................................(a word)

How can I do them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Plain TeX provides `\dotfill` in case of the period. `\leaders` and friends can be used for other characters or arbitrary stuff:

```
Hello \leaders\hbox{word}\hfill\null

H \leaders\hbox{word}\hfill\null

C \cleaders\hbox{word}\hfill\null

X \xleaders\hbox{word}\hfill\null

A\dotfill B

\bye
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- `\null` or something that is not a glue prevents that TeX removes the latest horizontal glue at the end of the paragraph.
- `\leaders` is often used in the table of contents. Then the dots are vertically aligned.
- `\cleaders` centers the stuff in the available space. Remaining space that cannot be filled by the leaders box is put at both ends.
- `\xleaders` puts the remaining space at each side of the repeated leaders boxes.

Comment: hey you stole my tick:-)

Answer (score 7):

use `\dotfill` ..................................................