# How to repeat a drawing

Tags: diagrams

I want to repeat a drawing in certain distances horizontally to form a group;
then move the whole group in certain distances vertically such as that on page 1 of the included `ions.tex`

Is there a more simple way, as for example using (for each), to make it look like that on pages 5-9 of the included `ions.tex`

The `ions.tex` is

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{tikz}   
\definecolor{darkgreen1}{rgb}{0.,0.55,0.1}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}

% begin individual ions     -------------------------------

% begin frame
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]%[plain,]
 \frametitle
{Polarization}%0


\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[c]{.7\textwidth}
\vskip -.52cm
\hskip -2.02cm
  \includegraphics [width=1.568\textwidth]{./Used/Ions/3dNerve/s3d-00-beig----_--.JPG}
\end{minipage}


\visible<1>
{
\begin{minipage}[c]{.7\textwidth}
\vskip -12.6cm
{
\begin{tikzpicture} [baseline=.12cm]
\draw [thin,orange,fill=yellow]
(.25,.25) --  (.25,0) --  (.5,0) --  (.5,.25) --  (.75,.25) --  (.75,.5) --  (.5,.5) --  (.5,.75) --  (.25,.75) --  (.25,.5) --  (0,.5) --  (0,.25) -- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\vskip -.7cm
\hskip -.06cm
{{\textcolor{red}{{\huge{\textbf{{Na}}}}}}}
}
\end{minipage}
}



\visible<1>
{
\begin{minipage}[c]{.7\textwidth}

\vskip -8.2cm
{
\begin{tikzpicture} [baseline=.12cm]
\draw [thin,orange,fill=yellow]
(.25,.25) --  (.25,0) --  (.5,0) --  (.5,.25) --  (.75,.25) --  (.75,.5) --  (.5,.5) --  (.5,.75) --  (.25,.75) --  (.25,.5) --  (0,.5) --  (0,.25) -- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\hskip -.75cm
{{\textcolor{red}{{\huge{\textbf{{K}}}}}}}
}
\end{minipage}
}



\visible<1->
{
\begin{minipage}[c]{.7\textwidth}
{
\vskip -12.7cm
\begin{tikzpicture} [baseline=.12cm]
\draw [thin,green,fill=green, fill opacity=0.4]
(0,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5)  -- (0,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\vskip -.55cm
\hskip .04cm
{{\textcolor{darkgreen1}{{\huge{\textbf{{Cl}}}}}}}
}
\end{minipage}
}



\visible<1->
{
\begin{minipage}[c]{.7\textwidth}
{
\vskip -8.7cm
\begin{tikzpicture} [baseline=.12cm]
\draw [thin,green,fill=green, fill opacity=0.4]
(0,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5)  -- (0,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\vskip -.55cm
\hskip -.22cm
{{\textcolor{darkgreen1}{{\Large{\textbf{{HCO$_{3}$}}}}}}}
}
\end{minipage}
}




\visible<2>
{
\begin{minipage}[c]{.7\textwidth}

\vskip -14.8cm
{
\begin{tikzpicture} [baseline=.12cm]
\draw [thin,orange,fill=yellow]
(.25,.25) --  (.25,0) --  (.5,0) --  (.5,.25) --  (.75,.25) --  (.75,.5) --  (.5,.5) --  (.5,.75) --  (.25,.75) --  (.25,.5) --  (0,.5) --  (0,.25) -- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\vskip -.7cm
\hskip -.06cm
{{\textcolor{red}{{\huge{\textbf{{Na}}}}}}}
}
\end{minipage}
}



\visible<2>
{
\begin{minipage}[c]{.7\textwidth}

\vskip -13.8cm
{
\begin{tikzpicture} [baseline=.12cm]
\draw [thin,orange,fill=yellow]
(.25,.25) --  (.25,0) --  (.5,0) --  (.5,.25) --  (.75,.25) --  (.75,.5) --  (.5,.5) --  (.5,.75) --  (.25,.75) --  (.25,.5) --  (0,.5) --  (0,.25) -- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\hskip -.75cm
{{\textcolor{red}{{\huge{\textbf{{K}}}}}}}
}
\end{minipage}
}




\visible<3>
{
\begin{minipage}[c]{.7\textwidth}

\vskip -14.2cm
{
\begin{tikzpicture} [baseline=.12cm]
\draw [thin,orange,fill=yellow]
(.25,.25) --  (.25,0) --  (.5,0) --  (.5,.25) --  (.75,.25) --  (.75,.5) --  (.5,.5) --  (.5,.75) --  (.25,.75) --  (.25,.5) --  (0,.5) --  (0,.25) -- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\vskip -.7cm
\hskip -.06cm
{{\textcolor{red}{{\huge{\textbf{{Na}}}}}}}
}
\end{minipage}
}



\visible<3>
{
\begin{minipage}[c]{.7\textwidth}

\vskip -17.8cm
{
\begin{tikzpicture} [baseline=.12cm]
\draw [thin,orange,fill=yellow]
(.25,.25) --  (.25,0) --  (.5,0) --  (.5,.25) --  (.75,.25) --  (.75,.5) --  (.5,.5) --  (.5,.75) --  (.25,.75) --  (.25,.5) --  (0,.5) --  (0,.25) -- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\hskip -.75cm
{{\textcolor{red}{{\huge{\textbf{{K}}}}}}}
}
\end{minipage}
}




\visible<4>
{
\begin{minipage}[c]{.7\textwidth}

\vskip -15.cm
{
\begin{tikzpicture} [baseline=.12cm]
\draw [thin,orange,fill=yellow]
(.25,.25) --  (.25,0) --  (.5,0) --  (.5,.25) --  (.75,.25) --  (.75,.5) --  (.5,.5) --  (.5,.75) --  (.25,.75) --  (.25,.5) --  (0,.5) --  (0,.25) -- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\vskip -.7cm
\hskip -.06cm
{{\textcolor{red}{{\huge{\textbf{{Na}}}}}}}
}
\end{minipage}
}



\visible<4>
{
\begin{minipage}[c]{.7\textwidth}

\vskip -21.cm
{
\begin{tikzpicture} [baseline=.12cm]
\draw [thin,orange,fill=yellow]
(.25,.25) --  (.25,0) --  (.5,0) --  (.5,.25) --  (.75,.25) --  (.75,.5) --  (.5,.5) --  (.5,.75) --  (.25,.75) --  (.25,.5) --  (0,.5) --  (0,.25) -- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\hskip -.75cm
{{\textcolor{red}{{\huge{\textbf{{K}}}}}}}
}
\end{minipage}
}

\end{figure}


\end{frame} 
% end frame

% end individual ions     -------------------------------
















% begin frame
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]%[plain,]
 \frametitle
{Polarization}%1


\begin{figure}

\begin{minipage}[c]{.7\textwidth}
\vskip -.52cm
\hskip -2.02cm
  \includegraphics[width=1.568\textwidth]{./Used/Ions/3dNerve/s3d-00-beig----_--.JPG}
\end{minipage}




\begin{minipage}[c]{.7\textwidth}
\vskip -11.8cm
\visible<1-2>
{
\begin{tikzpicture}% [baseline=1.2in]
\hskip -1.6cm
\draw [thick,orange,fill=yellow] (.25,.25) -- (.25,0) -- (.5,0) -- (.5,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (.5,.5) -- (.5,.75) -- (.25,.75) -- (.25,.5) -- (0,.5) -- (0,.25) -- (.25,.25) ;
\hskip 1.85cm
\draw [thick,orange,fill=yellow] (.25,.25) -- (.25,0) -- (.5,0) -- (.5,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (.5,.5) -- (.5,.75) -- (.25,.75) -- (.25,.5) -- (0,.5) -- (0,.25) -- (.25,.25) ;
\hskip 1.85cm
\draw [thick,orange,fill=yellow] (.25,.25) -- (.25,0) -- (.5,0) -- (.5,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (.5,.5) -- (.5,.75) -- (.25,.75) -- (.25,.5) -- (0,.5) -- (0,.25) -- (.25,.25) ;
\hskip 1.85cm
\draw [thick,orange,fill=yellow] (.25,.25) -- (.25,0) -- (.5,0) -- (.5,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (.5,.5) -- (.5,.75) -- (.25,.75) -- (.25,.5) -- (0,.5) -- (0,.25) -- (.25,.25) ;
\hskip 1.85cm
\draw [thick,orange,fill=yellow] (.25,.25) -- (.25,0) -- (.5,0) -- (.5,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (.5,.5) -- (.5,.75) -- (.25,.75) -- (.25,.5) -- (0,.5) -- (0,.25) -- (.25,.25) ;
\hskip 1.85cm
\draw [thick,orange,fill=yellow] (.25,.25) -- (.25,0) -- (.5,0) -- (.5,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (.5,.5) -- (.5,.75) -- (.25,.75) -- (.25,.5) -- (0,.5) -- (0,.25) -- (.25,.25) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\vskip -.7cm
\hskip -1.7cm
\visible<1-2>
{{\textcolor{red}{{\huge{\textbf{{Na~~~~~Na~~~~~Na~~~~~Na~~~~~Na~~~~~Na}}}}}}}
\end{minipage}




\begin{minipage}[c]{.7\textwidth}
\vskip -11.6cm
{
\begin{tikzpicture}% [baseline=1.2in]
\hskip 1.2cm
\draw [thick,green,fill=green](0,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5)  -- (0,.5);
\hskip 1.8cm
\draw [thick,green,fill=green](0,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5)  -- (0,.5);
\hskip 1.8cm
\draw [thick,green,fill=green](0,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5)  -- (0,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\vskip -.5cm
\hskip 1.2cm
{{\textcolor{darkgreen1}{{\huge{\textbf{{Cl~~~~Cl~~~~Cl}}}}}}}
\end{minipage}




\begin{minipage}[c]{.7\textwidth}
\vskip -9.4cm
\visible<1-2>
{
\begin{tikzpicture}% [baseline=1.2in]
\hskip 2.1cm
\draw [thick,orange,fill=yellow] (.25,.25) -- (.25,0) -- (.5,0) -- (.5,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (.5,.5) -- (.5,.75) -- (.25,.75) -- (.25,.5) -- (0,.5) -- (0,.25) -- (.25,.25) ;
\hskip 1.85cm
\draw [thick,orange,fill=yellow] (.25,.25) -- (.25,0) -- (.5,0) -- (.5,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (.5,.5) -- (.5,.75) -- (.25,.75) -- (.25,.5) -- (0,.5) -- (0,.25) -- (.25,.25) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\vskip -.7cm
\hskip -1.5cm
\visible<1-2>
{{\textcolor{red}{{\huge{\textbf{{~~~~~~~~~~~~~~K~~~~~K}}}}}}}
\end{minipage}




\begin{minipage}[c]{.7\textwidth}
\vskip -9.cm
{
\begin{tikzpicture}% [baseline=1.2in]
\hskip -.6cm
\draw [thick,green,fill=green](0,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5)  -- (0,.5);
\hskip 1.8cm
\draw [thick,green,fill=green](0,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5)  -- (0,.5);
\hskip 3.6cm
\draw [thick,green,fill=green](0,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5)  -- (0,.5);
\hskip 1.8cm
\draw [thick,green,fill=green](0,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5)  -- (0,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\vskip -.45cm
\hskip -.88cm
{{\textcolor{darkgreen1}{{\Large{\textbf{{HCO$_{3}$~~~HCO$_{3}$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~HCO$_{3}$~~~HCO$_{3}$}}}}}}}
\end{minipage}

\end{figure}




\begin{minipage}[c]{1\textwidth}
\vskip -3.cm
\begin{center}
\visible<1>
{\textcolor{brown}{{\Large{\textbf{{Polarized State}}}}}}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[c]{1\textwidth}
\vskip -3.8cm
\begin{center}
\visible<2>
{\textcolor{brown}{{\Large{\textbf{{A stimulus causes \\depolarization of the nerve fibre}}}}}}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}

\begin{figure}




\begin{minipage}[c]{.7\textwidth}
\vskip -17.6cm
\visible<3>
{
\begin{tikzpicture}% [baseline=1.2in]
\hskip -1.6cm
\draw [thick,orange,fill=yellow] (.25,.25) -- (.25,0) -- (.5,0) -- (.5,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (.5,.5) -- (.5,.75) -- (.25,.75) -- (.25,.5) -- (0,.5) -- (0,.25) -- (.25,.25) ;
\hskip 1.85cm
\draw [thick,orange,fill=yellow] (.25,.25) -- (.25,0) -- (.5,0) -- (.5,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (.5,.5) -- (.5,.75) -- (.25,.75) -- (.25,.5) -- (0,.5) -- (0,.25) -- (.25,.25) ;
\hskip 1.85cm
\draw [thick,orange,fill=yellow] (.25,.25) -- (.25,0) -- (.5,0) -- (.5,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (.5,.5) -- (.5,.75) -- (.25,.75) -- (.25,.5) -- (0,.5) -- (0,.25) -- (.25,.25) ;
\hskip 1.85cm
\draw [thick,orange,fill=yellow] (.25,.25) -- (.25,0) -- (.5,0) -- (.5,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (.5,.5) -- (.5,.75) -- (.25,.75) -- (.25,.5) -- (0,.5) -- (0,.25) -- (.25,.25) ;
\hskip 1.85cm
\draw [thick,orange,fill=yellow] (.25,.25) -- (.25,0) -- (.5,0) -- (.5,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (.5,.5) -- (.5,.75) -- (.25,.75) -- (.25,.5) -- (0,.5) -- (0,.25) -- (.25,.25) ;
\hskip 1.85cm
\draw [thick,orange,fill=yellow] (.25,.25) -- (.25,0) -- (.5,0) -- (.5,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (.5,.5) -- (.5,.75) -- (.25,.75) -- (.25,.5) -- (0,.5) -- (0,.25) -- (.25,.25) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\vskip -.7cm
\hskip -1.7cm
\visible<3>
{{\textcolor{red}{{\huge{\textbf{{Na~~~~~Na~~~~~Na~~~~~Na~~~~~Na~~~~~Na}}}}}}}
\end{minipage}


\begin{minipage}[c]{.7\textwidth}
\vskip -16.cm
\visible<3>
{
\begin{tikzpicture}% [baseline=1.2in]
\hskip 2.1cm
\draw [thick,orange,fill=yellow] (.25,.25) -- (.25,0) -- (.5,0) -- (.5,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (.5,.5) -- (.5,.75) -- (.25,.75) -- (.25,.5) -- (0,.5) -- (0,.25) -- (.25,.25) ;
\hskip 1.85cm
\draw [thick,orange,fill=yellow] (.25,.25) -- (.25,0) -- (.5,0) -- (.5,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (.5,.5) -- (.5,.75) -- (.25,.75) -- (.25,.5) -- (0,.5) -- (0,.25) -- (.25,.25) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\vskip -.7cm
\hskip -1.5cm
\visible<3>
{{\textcolor{red}{{\huge{\textbf{{~~~~~~~~~~~~~~K~~~~~K}}}}}}}
\end{minipage}


\end{figure}




\begin{figure}

\begin{minipage}[c]{.7\textwidth}
\vskip -17.8cm
\visible<4>
{
\begin{tikzpicture}% [baseline=1.2in]
\hskip -1.6cm
\draw [thick,orange,fill=yellow] (.25,.25) -- (.25,0) -- (.5,0) -- (.5,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (.5,.5) -- (.5,.75) -- (.25,.75) -- (.25,.5) -- (0,.5) -- (0,.25) -- (.25,.25) ;
\hskip 1.85cm
\draw [thick,orange,fill=yellow] (.25,.25) -- (.25,0) -- (.5,0) -- (.5,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (.5,.5) -- (.5,.75) -- (.25,.75) -- (.25,.5) -- (0,.5) -- (0,.25) -- (.25,.25) ;
\hskip 1.85cm
\draw [thick,orange,fill=yellow] (.25,.25) -- (.25,0) -- (.5,0) -- (.5,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (.5,.5) -- (.5,.75) -- (.25,.75) -- (.25,.5) -- (0,.5) -- (0,.25) -- (.25,.25) ;
\hskip 1.85cm
\draw [thick,orange,fill=yellow] (.25,.25) -- (.25,0) -- (.5,0) -- (.5,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (.5,.5) -- (.5,.75) -- (.25,.75) -- (.25,.5) -- (0,.5) -- (0,.25) -- (.25,.25) ;
\hskip 1.85cm
\draw [thick,orange,fill=yellow] (.25,.25) -- (.25,0) -- (.5,0) -- (.5,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (.5,.5) -- (.5,.75) -- (.25,.75) -- (.25,.5) -- (0,.5) -- (0,.25) -- (.25,.25) ;
\hskip 1.85cm
\draw [thick,orange,fill=yellow] (.25,.25) -- (.25,0) -- (.5,0) -- (.5,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (.5,.5) -- (.5,.75) -- (.25,.75) -- (.25,.5) -- (0,.5) -- (0,.25) -- (.25,.25) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\vskip -.7cm
\hskip -1.7cm
\visible<4>
{{\textcolor{red}{{\huge{\textbf{{Na~~~~~Na~~~~~Na~~~~~Na~~~~~Na~~~~~Na}}}}}}}
\end{minipage}


\begin{minipage}[c]{.7\textwidth}
\vskip -21.4cm
\visible<4>
{
\begin{tikzpicture}% [baseline=1.2in]
\hskip 2.1cm
\draw [thick,orange,fill=yellow] (.25,.25) -- (.25,0) -- (.5,0) -- (.5,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (.5,.5) -- (.5,.75) -- (.25,.75) -- (.25,.5) -- (0,.5) -- (0,.25) -- (.25,.25) ;
\hskip 1.85cm
\draw [thick,orange,fill=yellow] (.25,.25) -- (.25,0) -- (.5,0) -- (.5,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (.5,.5) -- (.5,.75) -- (.25,.75) -- (.25,.5) -- (0,.5) -- (0,.25) -- (.25,.25) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\vskip -.7cm
\hskip -1.5cm
\visible<4>
{{\textcolor{red}{{\huge{\textbf{{~~~~~~~~~~~~~~K~~~~~K}}}}}}}
\end{minipage}

\end{figure}




\begin{figure}

\begin{minipage}[c]{.7\textwidth}
\vskip -19.6cm
\visible<5>
{
\begin{tikzpicture}% [baseline=1.2in]
\hskip -1.6cm
\draw [thick,orange,fill=yellow] (.25,.25) -- (.25,0) -- (.5,0) -- (.5,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (.5,.5) -- (.5,.75) -- (.25,.75) -- (.25,.5) -- (0,.5) -- (0,.25) -- (.25,.25) ;
\hskip 1.85cm
\draw [thick,orange,fill=yellow] (.25,.25) -- (.25,0) -- (.5,0) -- (.5,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (.5,.5) -- (.5,.75) -- (.25,.75) -- (.25,.5) -- (0,.5) -- (0,.25) -- (.25,.25) ;
\hskip 1.85cm
\draw [thick,orange,fill=yellow] (.25,.25) -- (.25,0) -- (.5,0) -- (.5,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (.5,.5) -- (.5,.75) -- (.25,.75) -- (.25,.5) -- (0,.5) -- (0,.25) -- (.25,.25) ;
\hskip 1.85cm
\draw [thick,orange,fill=yellow] (.25,.25) -- (.25,0) -- (.5,0) -- (.5,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (.5,.5) -- (.5,.75) -- (.25,.75) -- (.25,.5) -- (0,.5) -- (0,.25) -- (.25,.25) ;
\hskip 1.85cm
\draw [thick,orange,fill=yellow] (.25,.25) -- (.25,0) -- (.5,0) -- (.5,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (.5,.5) -- (.5,.75) -- (.25,.75) -- (.25,.5) -- (0,.5) -- (0,.25) -- (.25,.25) ;
\hskip 1.85cm
\draw [thick,orange,fill=yellow] (.25,.25) -- (.25,0) -- (.5,0) -- (.5,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (.5,.5) -- (.5,.75) -- (.25,.75) -- (.25,.5) -- (0,.5) -- (0,.25) -- (.25,.25) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\vskip -.7cm
\hskip -1.7cm
\visible<5>
{{\textcolor{red}{{\huge{\textbf{{Na~~~~~Na~~~~~Na~~~~~Na~~~~~Na~~~~~Na}}}}}}}
\end{minipage}


\begin{minipage}[c]{.7\textwidth}
\vskip -24.8cm
\visible<5>
{
\begin{tikzpicture}% [baseline=1.2in]
\hskip 2.1cm
\draw [thick,orange,fill=yellow] (.25,.25) -- (.25,0) -- (.5,0) -- (.5,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (.5,.5) -- (.5,.75) -- (.25,.75) -- (.25,.5) -- (0,.5) -- (0,.25) -- (.25,.25) ;
\hskip 1.85cm
\draw [thick,orange,fill=yellow] (.25,.25) -- (.25,0) -- (.5,0) -- (.5,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (.5,.5) -- (.5,.75) -- (.25,.75) -- (.25,.5) -- (0,.5) -- (0,.25) -- (.25,.25) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\vskip -.7cm
\hskip -1.5cm
\visible<5>
{{\textcolor{red}{{\huge{\textbf{{~~~~~~~~~~~~~~K~~~~~K}}}}}}}
\end{minipage}


\end{figure}




\begin{minipage}[c]{1\textwidth}
\vskip -13.1cm
\begin{center}
\visible<5>
{\textcolor{brown}{{\Large{\textbf{{Reversed Polarized (Depolarized) State}}}}}}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}


\end{frame} 
% end frame


\end{document}
```

[image: ions1[![ions2[![ions3[![ions4[![ions5[![ions6[![ions7[![ions8[![ions9]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4unvr.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4unvr.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4unvr.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4unvr.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4unvr.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4unvr.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4unvr.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4unvr.jpg)
[[image: s3d-00-beig----_--.JPG]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8LZx.jpg)

[image]

Comment: @Hany-- Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. To add an image press `Ctrl+G`, a floating window will appear, just drag your image and drop on the opened window, then press `Add picture` .

Comment: To add code, paste it directly into the question. Can you add the code for a single drawing, in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? (I.e., we should be able to copy the code into an empty file and compile it without making any modifications.)

Comment: The easiest, fastest and most useful way is to use \savebox and \usebox.  (You also get the height, width and depth.)

Comment: Hi! ions.tex included...where?

Comment: [Crosspost](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=26951&view=unread#unread)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered your [LaTeX Community](http://latex-community.org/forum) crosspost and answered there. [This TikZ suggestion](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=92742#p92742) was my answer:

There are several possibilities:

- classic macros storing a series of TikZ commands
- `\savebox` for a TikZ picture, then `\usebox` to print this box as copies several times
- a TikZ `\foreach` loop
- TikZ `pic` objects

Since the first two are classic LaTeX, I show a TikZ `\foreach` loop solution:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \pos in {0,...,5} {
    \node at (1.85*\pos,0) { \tikz\draw [thick,orange,fill=yellow]
      (.25,.25) -- (.25,0) -- (.5,0)   -- (.5,.25)  -- (.75,.25) --
      (.75,.5)  -- (.5,.5) -- (.5,.75) -- (.25,.75) -- (.25,.5)  --
      (0,.5)    -- (0,.25) -- (.25,.25) ;} ;}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: How can you tell when nesting `tikzpicture`s is ***not*** going to be problematic, given that it often is?

Comment: @cr Well, it's drawing, we will immediately see if there would be a problem such a with inheriting a style from an outer TikZ picture. Then, `\savebox` is a safe box.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution which I wrote [here as TikZ pic example](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=92743#p92743):

- globally define a pic style with a name, which you can use any time you want (well you could do it locally as well)
- apply it in any TikZ drawing with a loop command or other commands

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  cross/.pic = {
    \draw [thick,orange,fill=yellow]
      (.25,.25) -- (.25,0) -- (.5,0)   -- (.5,.25)  -- (.75,.25) --
      (.75,.5)  -- (.5,.5) -- (.5,.75) -- (.25,.75) -- (.25,.5)  --
      (0,.5)    -- (0,.25) -- (.25,.25) ;}
}
\tikz \pic foreach \pos in {0,...,5} at (1.85*\pos,0) {cross};
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 2):

You asked to repeat something for a certain distance.  The standard TeX mechanism for repeating something to fill available space is `\leaders`, which is a generalisation of `\dotfill`.  There is also `\cleaders` which is the same, but centred.

See also: [How to print a row of points (or any other character) in plain TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181013/how-to-print-a-row-of-points-or-any-other-character-in-plain-tex)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=12cm,paperheight=7cm,margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\noindent \vrule$\leftarrow$ left margin \hfill right margin $\rightarrow$\vrule

\bigskip

\noindent \vrule$\leftarrow$ left margin \dotfill right margin $\rightarrow$\vrule

\bigskip

\noindent \vrule$\leftarrow$ left margin \leaders \hbox{\tt :-)} \hfill right margin $\rightarrow$\vrule

\bigskip

\noindent
\vrule$\leftarrow$
\cleaders
    \hbox{\hskip 2mm%
        \tikz[baseline={(0,0)}] \draw [line width=.2mm,fill=yellow]
        (0,0) circle[radius=4mm] (1.5mm,1.5mm) circle[radius=.2mm] (-1.5mm,1.5mm) circle[radius=.2mm]
        (-135:2.5mm) arc[start angle=-135,end angle=-45,radius=2.5mm];%
        \hskip 2mm}
    \hfill
$\rightarrow$\vrule

\end{document}
```

[image]